# Get particular data with multiple index value with/without loop in cakephp

Tags: php

I have an array in which i want only lineNo and Isdirty field in each array .
My demo code is

```
Array
(
    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ObjectType] => 12
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [CompanyID] => 1
                    [BranchID] => 46
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-25 05:10:15
                    [RevisionNumber] => 6
                    [IsDirty] => 
                )
        )
    [TaxConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 2
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                    [ItemGroupID] => 
                    [TaxID] => 
                    [CalculationType_080] => 430
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                    [ItemGroupID] => 
                    [TaxID] => 
                    [CalculationType_080] => 372
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Only LineNo And Isdirty field want in every index array .So please suggest me solution.

Comment: Could you please update your question and put original php array not dump?

Comment: Original php array?? this is my original array.

Comment: Use `array_map()` with `array_intersect()`

Comment: @hindmost: can u sand code how to use this array_map /array_intersect function.

Comment: @Abhishek You can do that simple iterating. See my answer and demo. With original array I meant state php object in your question. You have put `var_dump` output of your php array. Anyway, I have provided an example array as yours in my demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sue following;

```
$finalArr = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
        $finalArr[$key][] = array(
            "LineNo" => $v["LineNo"],
            "IsDirty" => $v["IsDirty"]
        );
    }   
}
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/eNcWcE)**